# Selenium skips elements of the same class during iteration

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to iterate over a list of links on a [website][1] but Selenium is not able to locate particular and seemingly random ones. In particular, I am trying to click on each of the cities and extract the number of stores using a for loop but it always skips, say, "Alameda" among all some other cities even though when I see nothing different about the html code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)
driver.get("https://locations.traderjoes.com/ca/")
cities = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('itemlist')

for i in range(0, len(cities)):
            print(city_list[i])
            if cities[i].is_displayed():
                    cities[i].click()
                    num = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('address-left'))
                    num_stores_by_city.append(num)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/a[2]').click()
            else:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    cities[i].click()
                    num = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('address-left'))
                    num_stores_by_city.append(num)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/a[2]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will determine the cities and then loop through each gathering the number of stores and adding information to a dictionary type object:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
url = 'https://locations.traderjoes.com/ca/'
driver.get(url)
city_list = {}
city_index = 0
processing_cities = True

while processing_cities:

    cities = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.itemlist a')

    if city_index < len(cities):
        city_text = cities[city_index].text
        cities[city_index].click()
        store_locations = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.itemlist')
        city_list[city_text] = len(store_locations)
        driver.get(url)
        city_index += 1
    else:
        processing_cities = False

print(city_list)
```

One of the issues you were running into was that once you click on an element your previously found elements become stale.  You need to re-find previously found elements to interact with them again.